# Why does it iterate one more time even if it is NULL?

Tags: c, linked-list, null-pointer

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204668/pointer-set-to-null-but-not-in-debugger) .
What I want to understand is that when current_node is NULL, the compiler doesn't see it as NULL and iterates one more time.

```
    void printBranches(struct bank *head) {
    struct branch *current_node = head->branches;
    while (current_node != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", current_node->bname);

        current_node = current_node->nextb;
    }
}
```

This is my print function.

Even though I use ***current_node!=NULL*** condition it prints something like this:' ╨q%+☺ ' when it is supposed to be NULL which I assume that it points somewhere unused in the memory(that has no meaningful value inside of it).
Here my debugger shows addresses it points;

```
 current_node 0x27e6b5d1740 when it is not NULL

              0x27e6b5d17f0 when it is suppose to be NULL
              0xbaadf00dbaadf00d when compiler sees it as NULL
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I've realized that in the method I use for filling linked list's node after determining the name of the node I immediately create a new node in the memory and then go to next without setting it to NULL as @trincot mentioned in the comments.

```
  memcpy(new_branch->bname, entity, sizeof(entity));

        // Go next branch
        new_branch->nextb = malloc(sizeof(struct branch));
        new_branch = new_branch->nextb;
```

That's why the last non-filled node is not empty.

**Edit 2:** When I do what @trincot said in the comments I can not add a new node after the first node. So I've tried a different method.

```
while (current_node->nextb->nextb != NULL) {
    printf("%s ", current_node->bname);

    current_node = current_node->nextb;
}
```

when I do this problem is solved because I can print what I want without meaningless value.

Comment: It would help to see a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Either `current_node->nextb` is not NULL when you think it should be, or `current_node->bname` does not point to a valid string. Creating an example might help you to find the issue yourself or allow others to help you diagnose the issue. This simple example stops when it should: https://ideone.com/HnFHGu

Comment: If it prints something like `' ╨q%+☺ `, then `current_node` is clearly not `NULL`. On a desktop system, `current_node->bname` would cause a protection violation (SIGSEGV), killing the program. It would not be around to print garbage.

Comment: *"0x27e6b5d17f0 when it is suppose to be NULL"*: please provide the code that sets it to NULL and then prints it like this. This cannot happen. Instead you did *not* set it to NULL. If you really think you did, provide the code that we can reproduce the issue with.

Comment: I don't set it to NULL anywhere in my code. I've just created a head. From this head I've filled several nodes' name. So there are nodes that I didn't fill with anything. I want to get out of while loop when it encounters with non-filled branch node @trincot

Comment: If you didn't set it to NULL, then that is the problem. You should never leave pointers uninitialised.

Comment: Thank you @RetiredNinja.  As you've shown in your example code my code should work but in a method that I fill these nodes I use something like this:
new_branch->nextb = malloc(sizeof(struct branch));
new_branch = new_branch->nextb;
so that's why last node is not empty.

Comment: @trincot I use malloc method so I initialize a new node. When I try "current_node->nextb->nextb != NULL" it prints what I want.  (I've written in the edit 2 part)

Comment: The clear implication is that `head->branches` is not NULL for the first element... therefore it will print something

Comment: @Andrew yes, you are right

Comment: `memcpy(new_branch->bname, entity, sizeof(entity));` can be an unsafe way to copy a string since it does not guarantee adding the 0 terminator. Using `sizeof` instead of `strlen` may also be a problem if it is being used on a pointer or array that has decayed to a pointer. If `bname` is a pointer we can't see how/if memory is allocated for it. You should consider `strcpy` and `strlen` if this becomes and issue or if `bname` is a pointer and not an array in the node.